# Laravel pagination is not working in search page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pagination

I am using laravel 5.1. This is my code,

**routes.php**

```
Route::any('users/search', array('as' => 'adminuserssearch', 'uses' => 'UsersController@adminSearch'));
```

**UsersController.php**

```
public function adminSearch(){
    $input = Input::all();
    if(!empty($input)){
        $key = Input::get('key');
        $users =  User::where('users.name', 'like', '%'.$key.'%')
         ->orWhere('users.email', 'like', '%'.$key.'%')
         ->paginate(10);

        return view('admin.users.search', ['users' => $users,'tag' =>$key]);
    }
}
```

**search.blade.php**

```
{!! $users->render() !!} //Use this code for display pagination.
```

When I search for a user, the url is like,

```
http://myproject/admin/users/search?key=user
```

But when I click pagination link the url will be like,

```
http://myproject/admin/users/search/?page=2
```

the `?key=user` section will be lost from the url. How can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should append this param to your [pagination links](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination#displaying-results-in-a-view) .

```
{!! $users->appends(['key' => $tag])->render() !!}
```

Comment: Thank you, bro. It's was helpful for me.

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel 8 change your UsersController.php by adding **->withQueryString()** to ->paginate(10) e.g

```
public function adminSearch(){
$input = Input::all();
if(!empty($input)){
    $key = Input::get('key');
    $users =  User::where('users.name', 'like', '%'.$key.'%')
     ->orWhere('users.email', 'like', '%'.$key.'%')
     ->paginate(10)->withQueryString(); //add withQueryString()

    return view('admin.users.search', ['users' => $users]);
         }
   }
```

Yourwelcome: [Source](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#appending-query-string-values)

Answer (score 0):

You can costumize the paginator URL using the `setPath()` method.

You can add it to your controller like this `$users->setPath('custom/url');`

Answer (score 0):

use  **withQueryString()** after paginate as like  **->paginate(10)->withQueryString()**

Answer (score -2):

A solution that worked for me:

https://laravel.io/forum/11-15-2016-ho-to-paginate-search-results

The accepted solution says:

> in your view where you display pagination...
>
> ```
> {{ $results->appends(Request::except('page'))->links() }}
> ```

Comment: [This answer is being discussed on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388894/why-was-my-flag-on-a-seemingly-link-only-answer-declined-by-a-moderator)